# ImportExcel -Add-ExcelChart query on parameter -PivotTable

Tags: excel, powershell, epplus

i am testing a script where I want to create Mutliple charts with the same pivot data,
I am able to get the first chart using the below snippets

```
 $pivotTableParams = @{
    PivotTableName  = "PWAuditData1"
    Address         = $excel.Sheet1.cells["F1"]
    SourceWorkSheet = $excel.Sheet1
    PivotRows       = echo o_username
    PivotData       = @{'Total' = 'sum'}
    PivotTableStyle = 'Light21'

        PivotChartDefinition = @{
                        Title="Total Downloads by Users";
                        ChartType="ColumnClustered";
                        Column=5; Row=15; Width=600; Height=500;
                        YMajorUnit=500; YMinorUnit=100; 
                        LegendPosition="Bottom"
                                 }
}
```

and then call the above definition using

```
$pt = Add-PivotTable @pivotTableParams -PassThru
```

I want to use the same data from above Pivot Table and insert for example a doughnut chart for which i use the Add-ExcelChart

```
$pivotSheet=$excel.Sheet1

$pt1 = Add-ExcelChart  -Worksheet $excel.Sheet1 -PivotTable $pivotSheet.pivotTables[0] -ChartType Doughnut -Row 100 -Column 20 -PassThru
```

when the code runs, I am able to get the first chart, but for inserting the second chart it gives error as below,
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

image

Question:
What is the correct way to reference the existing Pivot object which is already? placed on the sheet ?

Thanks for looking to this,
RJ